# PromQL avg vs avg_over_time

Tags: promql

Over time functions are not supporting by/without syntax. Which is the mathematical difference between using avg_over_time(metric[1h]) and avg(metric[1h])?
Can a over time function be replaced with a function (in this case avg) with the same results? Thanks!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The `avg_over_time(m[d])` function performs the following:

- it selects all the time series with name `m`
- then for every selected time series it calculates the average value across raw samples on the time range `d` preceding every point on the graph.

The `avg(m)` function performs the following:

- it selects all the time series with name `m`
- then for every selected time series it selects the last raw sample value before every point on the graph. See [these docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#staleness) for more details.
- then for every point on the graph it calculates the average value across the selected values for every time series.

As you can see, `avg_over_time()` and `avg()` are quite different functions - `avg_over_time()` calculates distinct average values for every selected time series, while `avg()` calculates average values across the selected time series.

Comment: Thanks. It can be combined as subqueries to produce the proper output. Is there any drawback?

Comment: If you need calculating the average value across data points from multiple time series on the given `[d]` time range, then the following query could be used:
`sum(sum_over_time(m[d])) by (...) / sum(count_over_time(m[d])) by (...)`

Comment: I use the avg_over_time in Openshift and I see that the graph is actually a moving average. Is there a way to get and graph with a line that is constant over the given time range? Ideally I would like to say plot the average of the day (or <n> hours) not the moving average over the last 24 h which continues to fluctuate over time during a given day.

Comment: @user1708042 , Prometheus doesn't support dynamically calculated durations for `avg_over_time` or similar functions.

Answer (score 3):

Why can't you just use

```
avg(avg_over_time(m[d]))
```

instead of

```
sum(sum_over_time(m[d])) by (...) / sum(count_over_time(m[d])) by (...)
```

Comment: because `avg(avg_over_time(m[d]))` returns average of averages, which isn't equal to average. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95909/why-is-an-average-of-an-average-usually-incorrect

Answer (score 0):

- avg function return scalar， but avg_over_time return new instant vector.
- avg function require instance vector parameter, but avg_over_time function require range vector